# Requested unknown parameter'4' for row 0 ,when pulling data from mssql

Tags: php, sql-server

I get the following error, when fetching data from database through php.

[image]

Below is the sql query

```
SELECT dbo.ASD_Employees.firstname,dbo.ASD_Employees.lastname,dbo.ASD_InOutType.description,dbo.ASD_InOutTrans.textarea_desc,dbo.ASD_InOutTrans.trans_date,dbo.ASD_InOutTrans.trans_time FROM dbo.ASD_InOutTrans INNER JOIN dbo.ASD_Employees ON dbo.ASD_Employees.code=dbo.ASD_InOutTrans.employee_code INNER JOIN dbo.ASD_InOutType ON dbo.ASD_InOutType.code=dbo.ASD_InOutTrans.inouttype_code WHERE dbo.ASD_InOutTrans.employee_code=$u_4_digit AND dbo.ASD_InOutTrans.inouttype_code=$action_go AND dbo.ASD_InOutTrans.trans_date = '".$date_f."'"
```

Below is the PHP code for displaying in datatable.

```
else if((isset($_POST['date_from'])) && (isset($_POST['4_digit'])) && (isset($_POST['move_type']))){ //An ta exw ola
                    $date_from = $_POST['date_from'];
                    $u_4_digit = $_POST['4_digit'];
                    $action_go = $_POST['move_type'];
                    $date_seperator= multiexplode(array("-"," "),$date_from);  
                       $date_f = $date_seperator[0];
                       $time_f = $date_seperator[1];
                       $date_t = $date_seperator[5];
                       $time_t = $date_seperator[6];

                     date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Athens");
                     $date=   date("j/n/Y");
                     $qrr = ("SELECT dbo.ASD_Employees.firstname,dbo.ASD_Employees.lastname,dbo.ASD_InOutType.description,dbo.ASD_InOutTrans.textarea_desc,dbo.ASD_InOutTrans.trans_date,dbo.ASD_InOutTrans.trans_time FROM dbo.ASD_InOutTrans INNER JOIN dbo.ASD_Employees ON dbo.ASD_Employees.code=dbo.ASD_InOutTrans.employee_code INNER JOIN dbo.ASD_InOutType ON dbo.ASD_InOutType.code=dbo.ASD_InOutTrans.inouttype_code WHERE dbo.ASD_InOutTrans.employee_code=$u_4_digit AND dbo.ASD_InOutTrans.inouttype_code=$action_go AND dbo.ASD_InOutTrans.trans_date = '".$date_f."'");
                     $result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$qrr);
                     $count = 0;
                     while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result,SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC)){

                    ?>
                    <tr>
                     <td><?php echo $row[0]." ".$row[1]; ?></td>
                     <td><?php echo $row[2]; ?></td>
                     <td><?php echo $row[4]." / ".$row[5]; ?></td>
                     <td><?php echo $row[3]; ?></td>    
                     <td><?php echo $date_f." ".$u_4_digit." ".$action_go;?></td>    
                   </tr>

                    <?php
                     }

                }
            }
                ?>
```

The problem is that I have a search form, that want to display multiple search criteria.I have five more search queries like this with date also.So the functions that I use in php are working.The problem in this query is that I get all the results but for ALL DATES  and not the parsed `date -> $date_f`

Comment: can you post the error please

Comment: And did you visit http://datatables.net/tn/4 like it said in the error message?

Comment: yes I couldn't find a useful answer